# How to keep track of clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<table ...` element with one column and many rows. Each of these rows is a link to an external shared drive.

```
<tr><td ><a href="file://xxx">Staff1</a></td></tr>
  <tr ><td ><a href="file://ccc">Staff2 </a></td></tr>
```

I need to keep track of the clicks on the links. How can I create some variables or anything to that would increment `++` as anybody click on the links.

```
         NumberOfClicks
Staff1        30
Staff2        50
```

I need these counts not to get deleted with the end of a session. I need them always accumulate

How can I do this?

---

My set up is the following:
I am the owner of a SharePoint website. I am not allowed to install SP Server (Otherwise I could easily use c#). So, I have to use JavaScript.

I tried to use `on click` function. However, the problem is that I can collect the number of clicks in a variable that would nullify after I close the browser. Is there any work around ?

Comment: anything you have tried if yes... share your code...

Comment: What is your setup? You serve this html from a webserver, or is it a local file viewed only in one browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some basic javascript will do the trick. Give your html links a common class like:

```
<tr><td><a class="my-link" href="file://xxx">Staff1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a class="my-link" href="file://ccc">Staff2 </a></td></tr>
```

Then in your javascript you can keep track of the number of clicks. I would advise using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for storing this number across sessions.

```
$(function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    $(".my-link").click(function() {
        clicks++;
        $.cookie('stored_clicks', clicks);
    });
});
```

Then to access the number of stored clicks when you want it, all you need to write is:

```
$.cookie('stored_clicks');
```

### **Edit:**

If you need access to every user and their number of clicks, why not store the values in some sort of hidden html?

The following is mostly pseudo-code, as I do not know what type of access you have to user details. This would also create quite a lot of redundant html, but you could tell exactly what link was clicked on as well.

```
<div id="hidden-stats" style="display: none"></div>

    $(".my-link").click(function() {
        clicks++;
        $.cookie('stored_clicks', clicks);
        $('#hidden-stats').append("<p>" + User.Details + $.cookie('stored_clicks') + "</p>");
    });
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. I did this. The problem is that this variable is stored in the users browser. However, I need to be able to see the number of clicks that other users did

Answer (score 4):

If you want to count the number of clicks just in one browser, just use the browser's local storage or cookies.

Otherwise, a much better method is to use server-side code, such as PHP, to count the number of pageviews.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the onclick function to display an invisible image (e.g. transparent gif) on your page, and watch how many times it is downloaded in the web statistics.